# jQuery Guillotine plugin - where to set height and width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the Guillotine plugin;

jQuery Guillotine Plugin v1.3.1 http://matiasgagliano.github.com/guillotine/

I am testing with the demo code but trying to set the width and height. No matter where I set the width and height the getData method fails. If I remove the width and height declaration (it defaults to 400 by 300 pixels) getData works again and the control panel is updated as you click zoom etc

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(function() {

var picture = $('#memberPhoto');
//SETTING THE WIDTH AND HEIGHT CAUSES GETDATA() TO STOP WORKING
//THE CONTROL PANEL DOES NOT UPDATE AND THE OUTPUT OF GETDATA IS EMPTY
//picture.guillotine({width: 250, height: 300});


  // Make sure the image is completely loaded before calling the plugin
  picture.one('load', function(){


    // Initialize plugin (with custom event)
    picture.guillotine({eventOnChange: 'guillotinechange'});
    picture.guillotine('fit')


    // Display inital data
    var data = picture.guillotine('getData');
    for(var key in data) { $('#'+key).html(data[key]); }

    // Bind button actions
    $('#rotate_left').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('rotateLeft'); });
    $('#rotate_right').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('rotateRight'); });
    $('#fit').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('fit'); });
    $('#zoom_in').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('zoomIn'); });
    $('#zoom_out').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('zoomOut'); });

    // Update data on change
    picture.on('guillotinechange', function(ev, data, action) {
      data.scale = parseFloat(data.scale.toFixed(4));
      for(var k in data) { $('#'+k).html(data[k]); }
      console.log(data);
    });
  });

  // Make sure the 'load' event is triggered at least once (for cached images)
  if (picture.prop('complete')) picture.trigger('load')




});
```

If I set the height and width directly in the source code all is fine.
Can anyone help..?

Thanks
Rolf

Comment: Do you get any undefined errors in the developer console when you run this script?

Comment: nope no errors at all...everything still works..ie I can resize, rotate etc but no values are given to the data object.

Comment: I just downloaded the demo. I will take a look and see if I can figure something out.

Comment: I believe I fixed the issue with adding the width and height property values.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are having is that the settings need to be passed in after the image has loaded.

JavaScript:

```
     jQuery(function() {        


var picture = $('#sample_picture');
 // Make sure the image is completely loaded before calling the plugin

 //SETTING THE WIDTH AND HEIGHT CAUSES GETDATA() TO STOP WORKING
//THE CONTROL PANEL DOES NOT UPDATE AND THE OUTPUT OF GETDATA IS EMPTY
 //picture.guillotine({width: 250, height: 300});


      picture.one('load', function(){

          /*PATCH: Settings need to be passed in after the object has loaded*/

        // Initialize plugin (with custom event)
        picture.guillotine({

            width: 250, height: 300,//<- Add plugin properties here.
            eventOnChange: 'guillotinechange'


        });
        // Display inital data
        var data = picture.guillotine('getData');
        for(var key in data) { $('#'+key).html(data[key]); }
        // Bind button actions
        $('#rotate_left').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('rotateLeft'); });
        $('#rotate_right').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('rotateRight'); });
        $('#fit').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('fit'); });
        $('#zoom_in').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('zoomIn'); });
        $('#zoom_out').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('zoomOut'); });
        // Update data on change
        picture.on('guillotinechange', function(ev, data, action) {
          data.scale = parseFloat(data.scale.toFixed(4));
          for(var k in data) { $('#'+k).html(data[k]); }
        });
      });
      // Make sure the 'load' event is triggered at least once (for cached images)
      if (picture.prop('complete')) picture.trigger('load');
    });
```